# How to hide particular A element inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="divclass">
   <a id="some_random_id_which_changes_everytime" class="otherclass" title="View Site">View Site</a>
</div>
```

I want to set display:none for this element "View Site". I tried the following codes but they didn't work. Please note I don't want to hide this whole div but just this particular A element inside it.

Code 1

```
.divClass [text='View Site']
{
   display:none;
}
```

Code 2

```
.divClass a[text='View Site']
{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Do you really use the class `otherclass` and the CSS selector `divClass` in the productive version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below.

```
div.divclass a[title="View Site"]
{
   display:none;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39XLT/)**

Alternatively, you can also declare values for `a[title="View Site"]` to hide without keeping the `div` inheritance.

For Instance,

```
a[title="View Site"]
{
   display:none;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO - 2](http://jsfiddle.net/39XLT/3/)**

If you want to compare the difference, you can check the below demo.

**[WORKING DEMO - FOR COMPARISON BETWEEN MULTIPLE TITLES](http://jsfiddle.net/39XLT/2/)**

Comment: This is not working. Just to test I tried with div.divclass { display:none; } and it hide the whole div but when I write a[title="View Site"] then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to hide using jquery ...

```
<div class="divclass">
  <a id="site" class="otherclass" title="View Site">View Site</a>
</div>
```

and js ..

```
$('#site').hide();
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/juwRg/)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.otherclass
{
display:none;
}
```

or

```
.divclass a.otherclass
{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Nathan said, or:

```
div.divclass a[title="View Site"]
{
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

This version will hide what you need but still take up space

Answer (score 0):

use the "child" selector:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Bla!
        </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div.divclass >a {display:none} /* any a that is direct child of div class divclass */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="divclass">
            data inside div before link
           <a id="some_random_id_which_changes_everytime" class="otherclass" title="View Site">View Site</a>
           data inside div after link
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```